# Redirecting logged in and non logged in users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to redirect in different jsp page logged in user for example "Admin" and in a different view a non logged in user. Here is my method till now...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lidhOfruesKerkues", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView lidhOfruesKerkues(@ModelAttribute("merrPersiperKerkues") Kerkues k, Ofrues ofrues,
            Authentication authResult) {
        ofruesService.addOfrues(ofrues);
        int kerkuesId = k.getKerkuesId();
        ofruesService.matchOfruesKerkues(kerkuesId);
        String role = authResult.getAuthorities().toString();
        if (role.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminHome");
        } 
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ofrojNdihmeView/getKerkuesAktiv");
    }
```

Error thrown is `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` that comes from "role" when I'm as a non logged in user. If I am logged in as ADMIN it works and redirects me as it should.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line specifically results in a NullPointerException?

Comment: NullPointerException results on 7th line @kaan. As @ Mark B said, I had to add checks if authResult or authResult.getAuthorities() were null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a null checks to your code, something like this:

```
String role = null;
if (authResult != null && authResult.getAuthorities() != null) {
    role = authResult.getAuthorities().toString();
}
if (role != null && role.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
```

Comment: As I said, "role" is throwing that. The line just before if condition.

Comment: Saying "role" is throwing it was not enough information. In the future please include the actual line number instead of just mentioning a variable name that happens to be on the line. You need to add checks if `authResult` or `authResult.getAuthorities()` are `null`.